# To create a battery symbol in bootstrap4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want a battery level indicator such that :-
1. I should able to change the level of battery based on the percentage values I am getting.
2. And I should able to change the level of battery level based on the percentage value like if it is below 20% then it is should indicate red color and for other levels other colors.

I know we can create through Html but it not so attractive one.

Comment: I would use FontAwesomes battery symbols, a full and an empty battery. Overlay each other and cut the width of the full battery to display only a certain percentage. Other than that please provide a [minimal reproduceable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: <i class="fa fa-battery-3 fa-rotate-0" style="font-size:50px;"></i>                             This is the icon I have used for displayng battery symbol but I am not getting how to change the level and color inside the battery

Answer (score 2):

You can customize by own style with help of FontAwesome `fa-battery-empty` class. So Inside  this class put `span` tag and map full width of empty battery shape so after mapping battery shape width gaping left+right then got `span` width is **73%**. We calculated `100% = 73%` It means `1 = 0.73`. So maintaining `span` width with help of css `calc()` function.
Ex: If your have 50% then set width like `width:calc(50% * 0.73)`.

I hope below snippet will help you lot.

```js
setInterval(function(){
  var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  document.getElementById("result").setAttribute("style", "width:calc("+x+"% * 0.73)");
  document.getElementById("result2").setAttribute("style", "width:calc("+x+"% * 0.73)");
  document.getElementById("result3").setAttribute("style", "width:calc("+x+"% * 0.73)");
},1000);
```

```css
.font-20px{font-size: 20px!important;}
.font-50px{font-size: 50px!important;}
.font-70px{font-size: 70px!important;}

.fa-battery-filling{
  position: relative;
}
.fa-battery-filling span{
  position: absolute;
  background: orange;
  top: 28%;
  height: 44%;
  left: 11%;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: 250ms ease;
}
.fa-battery-filling [style="width:calc(1% * 0.73)"],
.fa-battery-filling [style="width:calc(2% * 0.73)"], 
.fa-battery-filling [style="width:calc(3% * 0.73)"], 
.fa-battery-filling [style="width:calc(4% * 0.73)"], 
.fa-battery-filling [style="width:calc(5% * 0.73)"], 
.fa-battery-filling [style="width:calc(6% * 0.73)"], 
.fa-battery-filling [style="width:calc(7% * 0.73)"], 
.fa-battery-filling [style="width:calc(8% * 0.73)"], 
.fa-battery-filling [style="width:calc(9% * 0.73)"], 
.fa-battery-filling [style="width:calc(10% * 0.73)"],
.fa-battery-filling [style="width:calc(11% * 0.73)"],
.fa-battery-filling [style="width:calc(12% * 0.73)"],
.fa-battery-filling [style="width:calc(13% * 0.73)"],
.fa-battery-filling [style="width:calc(14% * 0.73)"],
.fa-battery-filling [style="width:calc(15% * 0.73)"],
.fa-battery-filling [style="width:calc(16% * 0.73)"],
.fa-battery-filling [style="width:calc(17% * 0.73)"],
.fa-battery-filling [style="width:calc(18% * 0.73)"],
.fa-battery-filling [style="width:calc(19% * 0.73)"],
.fa-battery-filling [style="width:calc(20% * 0.73)"]{
  background: red;
}
.fa-battery-filling [style="width:calc(90% * 0.73)"],
.fa-battery-filling [style="width:calc(91% * 0.73)"],
.fa-battery-filling [style="width:calc(92% * 0.73)"],
.fa-battery-filling [style="width:calc(93% * 0.73)"],
.fa-battery-filling [style="width:calc(94% * 0.73)"],
.fa-battery-filling [style="width:calc(95% * 0.73)"],
.fa-battery-filling [style="width:calc(96% * 0.73)"],
.fa-battery-filling [style="width:calc(97% * 0.73)"],
.fa-battery-filling [style="width:calc(98% * 0.73)"],
.fa-battery-filling [style="width:calc(99% * 0.73)"],
.fa-battery-filling [style="width:calc(100% * 0.73)"]{
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<i class="fa fa-battery-empty font-20px fa-battery-filling" aria-hidden="true">
  <span id="result" style="width:calc(10% * 0.73)"></span>
</i>
<i class="fa fa-battery-empty font-50px fa-battery-filling" aria-hidden="true">
  <span id="result2" style="width:calc(10% * 0.73)"></span>
</i>
<i class="fa fa-battery-empty font-70px fa-battery-filling" aria-hidden="true">
  <span id="result3" style="width:calc(10% * 0.73)"></span>
</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help and give you an idea.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#div1 {
  font-size:48px;
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<body>

<div id="div1" class="fa"></div>

<script>
function chargebattery() {
  var a;
  a = document.getElementById("div1");
  a.innerHTML = "&#xf244;";
  setTimeout(function () {
      a.innerHTML = "&#xf243;";
    }, 1000);
  setTimeout(function () {
      a.innerHTML = "&#xf242;";
    }, 2000);
  setTimeout(function () {
      a.innerHTML = "&#xf241;";
    }, 3000);
  setTimeout(function () {
      a.innerHTML = "&#xf240;";
    }, 4000);
}
chargebattery();
setInterval(chargebattery, 5000);
</script>

<p>This example demonstrates how to use an icon library to make an animated effect.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can we change only the color of the level inside the battery

Comment: actually it is icon it is default one eventhough if we change the color whole color will be changed not just only level color

Comment: Ahhh. I see. I think its a limitation then. Sorry, Bro. That's all I can help.